# Add Percentage rows to a Dataframe

Tags: r

I'm trying to bind two data frames. The first has the quantitative values, and the second has their relative value with the row. You can see that each data has the coluns 0, 1, 3, 5, 7. But how can I move the relative value immediately adjacent to the observed value?

I tried doing this:

```
cbind(x,y)
      0    1    3     5     7      0     1     3     5     7
11   747    0    0     0     0 100.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
12   249    0    0     0     0 100.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
13  1454    0    0     0   708  67.25  0.00  0.00  0.00 32.75
14   708    0    0     0     0 100.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
15  2661    0    0   249     0  91.44  0.00  0.00  8.56  0.00
```

Comment: if the column names are really the same, you can order by the column names:  `cbind(x,y)[, order(names(cbind(x,y)))]`.  There will be some renaming, but I find that to be convenient in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr's select, you can do it the following way:

```
library(dplyr)
colnames(df) <- c('col0', 'col1', 'col3', 'col5', 'col7', 'col0percent', 'col1percent', 'col3percent', 'col5percent', 'col7percent')
df <- select(df, col0, col0percent, col1, col1percent, col3, col3percent, col5, col5percent, col7, col7percent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not optimal but uses only the standard packages

```
nc <- ncol(x)
nr <- nrow(x)
i <- seq(1, by = 2, len = nc)
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = nc, nrow = nr))
df[,i]    <- x
df[,i+1]  <- y
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an index with the column order that you want.

```
cbind(x,y)[c(1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9,5,10)]
```